# Position a box with top/left inside a <div /> depending on the relative position of the cursor in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a big `<div />` container that has an image as a background. When the user moves the cursor over that element I need to show an another `<div />` that has information. I want this second one relative to the position of the cursor.

This is how far I am, I don't know how to exactly fit it on the mouse pointer: http://jsfiddle.net/cyX2m/

Updated: The problem is the position, not the event.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you just need to change event from `mouseover` to `mousemove`. Then you need to subtract the position of the element firing the event from the PageX/Y:

```
$("#big-area").bind("mousemove", function(e) {
    var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

    $("#data").html('e.pageY: ' + y + ', e.pageX: ' + x);

    $("#helper").css('top', y).css('left', x).show();
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cyX2m/4/)

Comment: not exactly what I am saying, I'm talking about the position but you're right about the mousemove event. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I would remove `position:relative` from the parent `div` so that the popup is positioned according to the `body` of the page. Then it will follow the cursor position exactly.

http://jsfiddle.net/cyX2m/2/